# AWK read file in reverse order and print specified columns

Tags: bash, shell, awk

Is it possible to read file in reverse order and print only specified columns using one awk command?
E.g there is a text file to be parsed:

```
A1 1 ABC 7
B2 2 CBZ 8
C3 3 XVY 9
```

To print lines in reverse order I use the following command:

```
awk '{a[i++]=$0}END{for(j=i-1;j>=0;j--)print a[j];}' file.txt
```

But I need to print only $1 and $3 columns? Desired output:

```
C3 XVY
B2 CBZ
A1 ABC
```

For sure it can be done multiple ways but single awk command is the target.

Comment: Just do `{a[i++] = $1 " " $3}` or `{a[i++] = sprintf("%s %s", $1, $3)}`

Comment: @WilliamPursell, thanks can it be done inside for loop ?

Comment: Sure, use `split`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your command you were storing entire line(`$0`) in array `a`, with little modification you can store required columns like below:

```
awk '{a[i++]=$1FS$3}END{for(j=i-1;j>=0;j--)print a[j];}'
C3 XVY
B2 CBZ
A1 ABC
```

Comment: I know you just copied the OPs attempt but there's no need for `i` since `NR` is builtin and awk arrays start at 1, not zero: `awk '{a[NR]=$1FS$3} END{for(j=NR;j>=1;j--)print a[j]}'`

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using another command then `tac + awk` does the job:

```
tac file | awk '{print $1, $3}'
```

```
C3 XVY
B2 CBZ
A1 ABC
```